# Increase a value for each iterate of for loop then assign to each thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

Program.cs:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
              {
                  c1.pr(i);
              });
            t.Start();
        }
    }

}
```

Class1.cs:

```
public class Class1
    {
        public void pr(int i)
        {
           Console.WriteLine((i).ToString());
        }
    }
```

Result:
2
2

I want the result to be 0 1. For each thread, value of i is assigned to function 'pr'.

If i add `t.Join()` after `t.Start()`  it works. But the joined thread has to wait until other threads have done their works, **is there any solution that provide the same result without using Join() function? I want to execute them at a same time**

Comment: Try to set temporary variable inside loop `var temp = i; Task.Run(() => c1.pr(temp));`

Comment: [Using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/using-the-iteration-variable-in-a-lambda-expression-may-have-unexpected-results)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are currently (perhaps unknowingly) doing is creating a thread for each iteration, this makes little sense. You should do something like this:

**Put the for-loop inside of the lambda function.**

```
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            c1.pr(i);
        }
    });
    t.Start();
```

Then you can create as many threads as you need and they will all print their own iterations of the loop variable.

**Small tangent:**
Interestingly the reason why a '2' is printed twice in your example is not intuitive and is a known "issue" with lambda functions, as they only capture the value of the closure. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp), if you are interested in the topic.

Comment: No problem. And don't get discouraged if people downvote your question. People here at StackOverflow try to help but expect stuff in a very specific format. Because this helps us help you. Good luck!

Comment: I'm interested in knowing what meaning you're trying to convey with the double quotes around "issue"?

Comment: @Enigmativity well, AFAIK it's not really an issue per se, rather, from what I understand it's the consequence of capturing the value of a variable while it's being iterated. I'm trying to convey that this is not a bug and it will not be fixed, but it can present a problem for those who are unaware.

Comment: Good explanation. I like it.